# Wordpress permalinks problem installed in laravel with apache

Tags: wordpress, laravel, apache, .htaccess

I have a laravel application in: **domain.com/co/app** that controls it **routes/web.php** with code `Route::post('/co/app'...` I have installed wordpress in the public folder of laravel (laravel/public/co) resulting in the blog: **domain.com/co**.

But when I activate the **permalinks** in wordpress the lavarel application (domain.com/co/app) I get a **wordpress 404 error.**

I have ignored the path of the application from the **wordpress .htaccess** `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(app) [NC]` but now I get an **apache 404 error** (The requested URL was not found on this server) and it does not show the laravel application.

This is the code of the .htaccess wordpress (laravel/public/co):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /co/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /co/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

This is the code of the .htaccesss de public (laravel/public)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

This is the Route code of the Laravel application (laravel/routes/web.php)

```
Route::post('/co/app', [
'uses' => 'App@aaa'
])->name('app');
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, in this special case, first you do **not** have to edit anything in the **.htaccesss of laravel/public** you only have to edit the **wordpress** (laravel/public/co). Ignoring the laravel application path with `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/co/app` and adding a **new module** that points to the **index.php of laravel/public**

The problem is that WordPress can intentionally edit your .htaccess and delete our modification, for that we use a hack that is explained [here](https://perishablepress.com/stop-wordpress-changing-htaccess/).

My final wordpress .htaccess code is:

```
<IfModule mod_ignore_wordpress.c>
# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /co/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /co/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /co/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/co/app
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /co/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
#new module
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /co/app
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```